# How can I get a thumbnail/preview frame from an uploaded mp4 video?

Tags: php, video, thumbnails, mp4

I am wondering what steps I would have to go through to grab an image of a frame from an mp4 video to use as its thumbnail.
Is there any way when uploading a file to grab its thumbnail info from the OS? Is there any open source methods or libraries that already have this capability?
If not, how simply could it be coded by hand using php?

I am not necessarily doing this; at this point researching feasibility!

Comment: Seen this question before on Stackoverflow. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thumbnail+video+php

Comment: Aha.. my initial searching didn't include 'thumbnail' and I wasn't getting anything.